Job prospects in USA with a UK Master's degree but no Bachelor's degree
I have decades of experience that could apply to a Master's degree program through the UK.
I never finished my Bachelor's in the USA.  I went to school and finished 1 year of it about 15 years ago.  I live in and plan on working in the USA, however, the traditional education path is the BS first then a Master's.  I only want the degree to qualify for a better-paying job as the only obstacle I repeatedly hear for hiring me in interviews is the lack of a degree.  I am nearly 50 and can't spend 7 years getting both a Bachelor's and Master's degree to qualify on paper so I have looked into this option.
My questions are:

To anyone who has gotten a UK Master's degree without having a Bachelor's degree first, was it a problem when trying to get hired in the US that you did not have a Bachelor's degree and went straight for the Master's?
How did you address the issue when asked about your lack of BS but having an MS?


I can't really give an answer, but note that a US bachelors is a generalist degree and a masters is a specialist degree. So, any benefit depends a lot on the jobs you seek. An alternative is to do a part time bachelors, nights and week-ends at some local college or university. Time will pass no matter what you do. Coursework toward any degree might be a benefit.

Why do you want a degree? For some box-checkers. lacking a Bachelor's degree may disqualify you even if you have a MS. On the other hand, I know people who got into professional programs (e.g., Dental School, Pharmacy School, Med School) without competing their undergraduate degrees, but have their doctorates and work as medical professionals. A lot is specific to your situation.

I'm voting to close as off-topic.  Your question is about how non-academic employers deal with a particular degree situation, not about what happens in academia.

More appropriate for The Workplace?

This doesn't seem to be a question about academia. Maybe indeed best migrated to Workplace as suggested above?

I don't get it. How can you have a master's degree without a bachelor's degree? Either you have an integrated master's degree which is 3 year of bachelor's plus one years of master's, or you have an independent master's meaning you got accepted based on your prior bachelor's degree.

Once you have a Master's, nobody is going to be concerned any more about your lack of a Bacherlor's degree. That's because you've demonstrated knowledge that exceeds what is necessary to get a Bachelor's, so people will no longer be concerned about the lack of the latter.
The issue for you will be to get into a Master's program without a Bachelor's degree. I suspect that having many years of experience in a particular field will count quite favorably in the eyes of admissions committees, as long as you can document industry experience that is comparable to what a graduating Bachelor's student would know.
My suggestion would be to go talk to the head of the graduate program at a couple of universities in your area. Introduce yourself and ask them how they would view your application. That's cheaper and faster than first writing an application and then seeing what happens. Personally, I've always appreciated people coming back from industry because they bring different perspectives that enrich the education of all students, in particular that of students who've come straight from undergraduate and have never worked in industry. So I'd give your application a chance, assuming you can someone show comparable experience.

"nobody is going to be concerned" sadly untrue. The prospective manager may not be concerned, but the admin assistant in HR who is screening applications and cannot tick "appropriate undergraduate degree" sometimes will be

As @Flyto notes, many universities administration will simply refuse to admit to any graduate program a student who does not have an undergrad degree... to the extent of over-riding departmental recommendations to admit. I've had the experience.
